Flutter GoRouter PopScope Widget Not Working
I'm working on a Flutter application using go_router for navigation and PopScope to handle back navigation. I'm experiencing issues with PopScope not behaving as expected.
Context:

I'm using go_router for routing in my Flutter app.

I need to show an AlertDialog when the user tries to navigate back from a specific route, but PopScope doesn't seem to work as intended.

I want to control the behavior when the back button is pressed and either allow or prevent the navigation based on user confirmation.


Code Example:
Here is the relevant code snippet where I configure PopScope and GoRouter:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:go_router/go_router.dart';

class AppNavigation {
  AppNavigation._();

  static final rootNavigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();

  static List<RouteBase> routes = [
    GoRoute(
      path: "/home",
      name: "Home",
      builder: (BuildContext context, GoRouterState state) {
        return HomePage();
      },
    ),
    // Other routes...
  ];

  static final GoRouter router = GoRouter(
    navigatorKey: rootNavigatorKey,
    routes: routes,
  );
}

class HomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Home')),
      body: PopScope(
        onPopInvoked: () async {
          final shouldExit = await showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Confirmation'),
              content: Text('Do you want to exit?'),
              actions: [
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(false),
                  child: Text('No'),
                ),
                TextButton(
                  onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(true),
                  child: Text('Yes'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
          return shouldExit;
        },
        child: Center(child: Text('Home Page Content')),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Issue:

The PopScope widget is supposed to intercept the back navigation and display an AlertDialog, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.

The AlertDialog does not appear when the back button is pressed, and the navigation behavior is not controlled.


What I’ve Tried:

Ensured that PopScope is correctly used within the Navigator widget.

Verified that GoRouter is properly set up and that the route configuration is correct.


Question:
How can I make sure that PopScope works properly with go_router? Is there a known issue or workaround for using PopScope with go_router to control back navigation?
Thank you for any help or insights!
What I Tried:

Implemented PopScope to handle back navigation within the GoRouter setup.

Used PopScope to show an AlertDialog asking the user for confirmation when they attempt to navigate back.

Configured the onPopInvoked callback in PopScope to display the AlertDialog and determine if navigation should proceed.


What I Expected:

When the back button is pressed, PopScope should intercept the event and show the AlertDialog.

The AlertDialog should give the user the option to either confirm or cancel the navigation.

If the user confirms, navigation should proceed. If the user cancels, the navigation should be blocked.


What Actually Happened:

The AlertDialog does not appear when the back button is pressed.

Navigation occurs immediately without showing the dialog, ignoring the PopScope configuration.



Beautiful made question, but it is clear you did not read the documentation since there is the exact use case in an example.

 void _onBackPressed({required BuildContext context}) {
      WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
        if (mounted) {
          showDialog(
            context: context,
            builder: (context) {
              return AlertDialog(
                title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
                content: const Text('Do you want to end the call?'),
                actions: [
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                    },
                    child: const Text('No'),
                  ),
                  TextButton(
                    onPressed: () {
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      Navigator.pop(context);
                      openCallEndReviewBottomSheet(context, navigationProvider);
                    },
                    child: const Text('Yes'),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
      });
    }

    return BackButtonListener(
      onBackButtonPressed: () async {
        _onBackPressed(context: context);
        return true;
      },
     child:Text('Test'),
    );


does this work on top-level routes to prevent closing the app? @Mah

I think you can find the pages from the router

As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

You should take a look at the canPop parameter of the PopScope widget because that parameter disables the back gesture.
The documentation has your use case as an example:
// COPIED AND PASTED FROM https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PopScope-class.html
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const NavigatorPopHandlerApp());

class NavigatorPopHandlerApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const NavigatorPopHandlerApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      initialRoute: '/home',
      routes: <String, WidgetBuilder>{
        '/home': (BuildContext context) => const _HomePage(),
        '/two': (BuildContext context) => const _PageTwo(),
      },
    );
  }
}

class _HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const _HomePage();

  @override
  State<_HomePage> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<_HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Page One'),
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pushNamed('/two');
              },
              child: const Text('Next page'),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class _PageTwo extends StatefulWidget {
  const _PageTwo();

  @override
  State<_PageTwo> createState() => _PageTwoState();
}

class _PageTwoState extends State<_PageTwo> {
  /// Shows a dialog and resolves to true when the user has indicated that they
  /// want to pop.
  ///
  /// A return value of null indicates a desire not to pop, such as when the
  /// user has dismissed the modal without tapping a button.
  Future<bool?> _showBackDialog() {
    return showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
          content: const Text(
            'Are you sure you want to leave this page?',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Nevermind'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, false);
              },
            ),
            TextButton(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                textStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.labelLarge,
              ),
              child: const Text('Leave'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pop(context, true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            const Text('Page Two'),
            PopScope(
              canPop: false,
              onPopInvoked: (bool didPop) async {
                if (didPop) {
                  return;
                }
                final bool shouldPop = await _showBackDialog() ?? false;
                if (context.mounted && shouldPop) {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                }
              },
              child: TextButton(
                onPressed: () async {
                  final bool shouldPop = await _showBackDialog() ?? false;
                  if (context.mounted && shouldPop) {
                    Navigator.pop(context);
                  }
                },
                child: const Text('Go back'),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

